# How to Create Android app

Tags: android

I created my project in cordova and its here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XdcR.png)

Here problem is i cant use cordova build function (it isnt work for me)

and now question is here :
can i compile it and make apk file from these files???
if yes how?

i have android studio installed but i dont know how to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

same as answer by Jackowski.

but,Make sure you import the "platform/android" directory underneath your cordova project (and you want to Import Project, not Open Project).

http://codeofandroid.blogspot.in/2016/02/import-cordova-project-in-android-studio.html

Answer (score 0):

Open Android Studio and select 'Import project' option. Then select your project location and you are ready to use Android Studio with your project.

More info at: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide/platforms/android/